# Firestore with service account

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, gcloud

I'm building a react native app (expo managed) and want to authenticate users using a phone number. To do so I need to convert the token I receive from Magic to a [JWT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). I'm unsure how to enable the service account. I have the private key, but it seems like I need to initialize the app using the same method I used to initialize firestore. Or can I combine the two keys?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking how to use a service account in your web app client code, that's not possible (and would also be incredibly insecure).  Service accounts are for use with secure backend code only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auth` Cloud Function takes in the DID token and converts it into a Firebase user access token. Pass the Firebase user access token into the `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken` method to authenticate user natively with Firebase.

Magic doesn't replace Firebase Auth, and can actually integrate seamlessly into it so you will be able to have the same permissions and database rules configurations as if it's native Firebase Auth.

User logs in with Magic link, which upon successful login, generates a DID token
The DID token is passed into the `auth` Firebase `httpsCallable` Cloud Function.
The auth Cloud Function takes in the DID token and converts it into a Firebase user access token
Pass the Firebase user access token into the `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken` method to authenticate user natively with Firebase

```
/* User login with Magic link to get DID token */
   const didToken = await magic.auth.loginWithMagicLink({ email });
   const auth = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("auth");

/* DID token is passed into the auth callable function */
   let result = (await auth({ didToken })).data;

/* Firebase user access token is used to authenticate */
   await firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(result.token);
```

You can follow this step for [Implement Auth Callable Function](https://magic.link/posts/magic-firebase-integration#implement-auth-callable-function) in this link. This will help you to convert your Magic DID token into a Firebase user access token.

Comment: I've realized the issue is because this code is web 8 not web 9.